# Design pattern for canceling a long task in a sub-thread

Tags: design-patterns, event

Suppose we have a file copy program. It has two threads, a UI thread displaying the progress of the copy operation and a work thread copying the file.
The UI has a button for canceling the process. Which pattern are you suggest here for transfering cancel event to copy thread?
I want an object-oriented solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java, use Thread.interrupt - this is exactly the scenario that system was designed for.

Otherwise, you'll need to look at what synchronisation primitives your language provides. If it has an Event synchronisation class, use that (periodically poll the event in the worker thread and terminate if it is fired, signal the event if the user clicks the button). Events are sometimes called Condition, so check for that name too.

If not, you'll have to implement one yourself, using whatever memory barrier primitive your language provides. All you need is a class with a boolean variable initialised to false and two methods: set, which sets the variable to true and executes a write barrier, and get, which executes a read barrier and returns the variable. In most languages, if you don't have explicit memory barrier operations, then you can use whatever mutual exclusion operation is provided instead.

Answer (score -1):

The `Command` pattern comes to my mind. You have a `Command` interface/trait/abstract class and create for example a `StopCopyingCommand` and send it to the copy thread.

The copy thread btw. could be implemented using the `State` pattern so that it accepts different kinds of commands for different states.

Comment: These seem like overkill for something that can be implemented with a single boolean state variable that's periodically polled.

Comment: I disagree. I can think of at least these states: `CopyingState`, `CopyingFinishedState`, `CopyingPausedState`, `CopyingFailedState`. A single boolean state variable will not be sufficient. And it is a code smell that can work for a quick'n'dirty toss-away hack, but we are on programmers.stackexchange here and we want to do things the right way. ;)

Comment: Why all those states? When the work is done, the worker thread can just report its final progress indication and die.

Comment: And what happens if the user wants to pause/resume the copying? Yes, the OP does not tell about this requirement and one can even use if/switch, but a good desing is using states from the beginning, imho, so that you can easily extend it when needed. Its not like stats are so much overhead.

Comment: The problem has some relation with synchronization. I know that these patterns are created for passing commands between objects, but there is a multi-thread app here and your response doesn't consider that.